# Google Photos: Changing from iPhone to Samsung S9

Tags: google-photos, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I’m switching from iPhone 5SE to Samsung Galaxy S9. I’ve used Google Photos to save my photos and videos. Is the change from phones going to impact my data on Google Photos? Basically, when I log into Google Photos on Samsung, will all of my photos be there?

Answer (score 0):

No. They will remain on Google Photos unless you select "save to phone" for each photo you want to be available offline. They won't be automatically downloaded to your new Samsung.